# How to Set Cookie in Session

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add cookies in my session where I want it to count the value, but I don't seem to get it to work.

This is my code so far.
Whenever I typ something in the value of setcookies i will just get that value. I already have a file called Cookies and it's working fine with out any issues. I have read different example on site, and youtube example, but I still don't get it why it won't increase the value of the cookie however I do it...

Edit: When i use them, they won't give me any error code or a message. Nothing actually happens, except the 0 is being typed in when it comes to sumOfAllRounds because the value is 0. That I do understand.

```
 setcookie("nbrOfRounds", "", time() + 3600);  
setcookie("sumOfAllRounds", "0", time() + 3600); 
 
setcookie("nbrOfRounds", "", time() - 3600);  
setcookie("sumOfAllRounds", "0", time() - 3600);
```

What I do want to happen is, every time i press the button "linkRoll", the cookies should change, for example if i press it 4 times it should say for on "nbrOfRounds", and ad the total of sum on the cookie "sumOfAllRounds" which never happens.
Hopefully this makes more sense what I am trying to accomplish.

```
    <?php 
// Delete Sessionen. 
function deleteSession() {

    session_unset();

    if( ini_get("session.use_cookies") ) {
        $sessionCookieData = session_get_cookie_params();
        $path = $sessionCookieData["path"];
        $domain = $sessionCookieData["domain"];
        $secure = $sessionCookieData["secure"];
        $httponly = $sessionCookieData["httponly"];

        $name = session_name();

        setcookie($name, "", time() - 3600, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
    }   
    session_destroy();
}

// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" >

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Roll the dice...</title>
        <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
        
<?php // class disabled     
$disabled = true; 

if( isset( $_GET["linkRoll"] ) ) {
    $_SESSION["sumOfAllRounds"] = 0; 
    $disabled = false;
}

if( isset( $_GET["linkExit"] ) ) {      
    //setcookie("nbrOfRounds", "", time() - 3600);  
    //setcookie("sumOfAllRounds", "0", time() - 3600); 
    deleteSession();
}

if( isset( $_GET["linkNewGame"] ) ) {
    echo ("New Game");
    //setcookie("nbrOfRounds", "", time() + 3600); 
    //setcookie("sumOfAllRounds", "0", time() + 3600); 
    $disabled = false;  
}
if( !isset($_GET["linkExit"]) && !isset($_GET["linkNewGame"]) &&
    isset($_SESSION["sumOfAllRounds"]) && isset($_SESSION["nbrOfRounds"])) {
        $disabled = false;
}
/*
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("DiceWithCookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(nbrOfRounds(), '', time() + 3600);
    //setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 3600);
}   
*/
?>
    </div>
        <a href="<?php echo ( $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>?linkRoll=true" class="btn btn-primary <?php if($disabled) { echo("disabled"); }  ?>">Roll six dices</a> <!--Makes it's disabled -->
        <a href="<?php ?>?linkNewGame=true" class="btn btn-primary">New game</a>
        <a href="<?php ?>?linkExit=true" class="btn btn-primary <?php if($disabled) { echo("disabled"); } ?>">Exit</a> <!--Makes the button disabled -->
        <script src="script/animation.js"></script> 

<?php
include ( "include/SixDices.php" );
include ( "include/OneDice.php" );

if (isset ($_GET ["linkRoll"])) {
    $oSixDices = new SixDices();
    $oSixDices -> rollDices ();

    echo( " <p> summan är " . $oSixDices -> sumDices() . "!</p>"); // Gives the totally sum of the last round
    
    echo ( $oSixDices -> svgDices() );
    // the total sum
    $value = $_SESSION["sumOfAllRounds"] ?? 0;
    //$value = strval($oSixDices ->sumDices()); 

    $value = $_SESSION["sumOfAllRounds"] ?? 0;
    if ($value == 0) {
        $_SESSION["sumOfAllRounds"] = $oSixDices->sumDices();
    } else {
        $_SESSION["sumOfAllRounds"] = $value += $oSixDices->sumDices();
    }

    echo ( "<p> Totalsumma: " . $value .  "</p>" );
    //$_SESSION["sumOfAllRounds"] = $value ; 

    // Total throws 
    $rounds = $_SESSION ["nbrOfRounds"] ?? ""; 
    $rounds++; 
    echo ( "<p> Antal kast: " . $rounds .   "!</p>"  );
    $_SESSION["nbrOfRounds"] = $rounds; // adds upp the rounds. 
    $disabled = false;      
    
    $medel =  $value/$rounds;   
    echo (" <p> Medelvärdet: ". $medel. "!</p>" );
    $disabled = false; 
}
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: presumably `enter code here` is a mistake from adding the question or is that where you expect additional code?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: No it was my mistake didn't notice it, thanks :)

Comment: `<?php ?>` does nothing. Can you simplify issue? Which `setcookie` fails, does it give error? What is being passed to it/what does it return?